# Regular expression for matching 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXX-XX' format javascript. X can be alpha or numeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried creating this but it doesn't seems to be working properly

```
(/^ [A-Z]\d{5} \- [A-Z]\d{5} \- [A-Z]\d{3} \- [A-Z]\d{2} $/))
```

Comment: (/^ [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$ - [a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$ - [a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$ - [a-zA-Z0-9]{2} $/))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[A-Z]\d{5}` means: any letter from `A` to `Z` and *then* five digits.

What you want is `[A-Z0-9]{5}` and similar. You also need to remove the spaces. And if you want to accept lower-case letters as well, use the `i` flag.

Full regex:

```javascript
/^[A-Z0-9]{5}\-[A-Z0-9]{5}\-[A-Z0-9]{3}\-[A-Z0-9]{2}$/i
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, But how can i remove the space? and [A-Z]\d{5} means XXXXX can be alpha or numeric, not the "letter from A to Z and then five digit". sorry for not making clear description.

Comment: @krunal.cp What do you mean? Just delete the whitespaces from the regex; see the full regex in this answer. They’re not in the format.

Comment: I mean no space should be there.

Comment: @krunal.cp He's saying that the regex _you_ posted means "any letter from A to Z and then five digits". And there is in-fact whitespace in the regex that you posted, which needs to be removed. The regex in this answer is correct.

Comment: Also, I think `[A-Za-z0-9]` would be preferable to using the case-insensitive flag.

Comment: Outside of a character class, javascript regex doesn't require the `-` character to be escaped.  `/^[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{3}-[A-Z0-9]{2}$/i` should be equivalent to your current regex.

Comment: @ach That would also be an option, but I don’t see why it would be considered preferable. Is it because it’s more immediately clear?

Comment: @Xufox Your reg seems to be working. Thank for the help.:)

Comment: I thought you could use [a-Z] to get both upper and lower case. Maybe it's not working in js.

Comment: @Qben Nope, `[a-Z]` means any Unicode character from `a` to `Z` which goes in the wrong direction as `Z` (U+005A) doesn’t come after `a` (U+0061). `[A-z]` also wouldn’t work because it includes `[`, backslash, `]`, `^`, `_` and the backtick.

Comment: @Xufox That and the regex becomes more portable, since different languages/platforms may require you to specify flags differently